# Solution to Excel Text Formatting in UserForm

Tags: excel, userform, textformat

I'm working with a UserForm and plan to perform calculations in my UserForm.
In order to present numbers in a 'correct way as text, I use the text format function.

I use the following syntax: `FORMAT(xxxx, "#'###")`.
All well, however, when xxxx < 1000, I get a string preceded with an apostrophe (that is the 1000s separator I use): 'xxx

Unfortunately, when this happens, I cannot use the string 'xxx for subsequent calculations. Hence `CDbl('xxx)` does not work.

Any suggestions to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For display only purposes:

```
Sub ForDisplayPurposes()
    Dim xxxx As Long, s As String
    xxxx = 123456
    s = Replace(Format(xxxx, "#,###"), Find:=",", Replace:="'")
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

[image]

To convert back to a number:

```
num = CDbl(Replace(s, "'", ""))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time & contribution. The second bit ( `num = CDbl(Replace(s, "'", ""))` ) is a smart way to circumvent the issue, really helps me out to perform the calculations. The text formatting works also but is a convoluted way to achieve it. Does this mean that for numbers < 1000, the text formatting with the "," the coma will not appear, but with the apostrophe as a separator, the apostrophe will appear?
`FORMAT(123, "#'###")` results in `'123` and
`FORMAT(123, "#,###")` results in `123`